# id values of different variables in python 3

Tags: memory, python-3.x

I am able to understand immutability with python (surprisingly simple too). Let's say I assign a number to

```
x = 42
print(id(x))
print(id(42))
```

On both counts, the value I get is

```
505494448
```

My question is, does python interpreter allot ids to all the numbers, alphabets, True/False in the memory before the environment loads? If it doesn't, how are the ids kept track of? Or am I looking at this in the wrong way? Can someone explain it please?

Comment: small numbers from -5 to 255 are interned

Comment: Oh, that is something I didn't know.. thank you Dan D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is an implementation detail (an internal optimization) calling **interning**.  This is a technique (used by implementations of a number of languages including Java and Lua) which aliases names or variables to be references to single object instances where that's possible or feasible.

You should not depend on this behavior.  It's not part of the language's formal specification and there are no guarantees that separate literal references to a string or integer will be interned nor that a given set of operations (string or numeric) yielding a given object will be interned against otherwise identical objects.

I've heard that the C Python implementation does include a set of the first hundred or so integers as statically instantiated immutable objects.  I suspect that other very high level language run-time libraries are likely to include similar optimizations:  the first hundred integers are used very frequently by most non-trivial fragments of code.

In terms of how such things are implemented ... for strings and larger integers it would make sense for Python to maintain these as dictionaries.  Thus any expression yielding an integer (and perhaps even floats) and strings (at least sufficiently short strings) would be hashed, looked up in the appropriate (internal) object dictionary, added if necessary and then returned as references to the resulting object.

You can do your own similar interning of any sorts of custom object you like by wrapping the instantiation in your own calls to your own class static dictionary.