# Comparing ints with 'is' keyword (or The Magical 257)

Tags: python, int, compare, equality

I came across a very odd behavior that I can't quite explain (running Python 2.7.6).

It is common knowledge that you shouldn't compare strings using `is` in Python. However, I was completely unaware that similar badness can happen trying to compare `int`s.

Take the following script for example:

```
for x, y in zip(xrange(0,399), xrange(1,400)):
    z = y - 1
    if x is z:
        res = 'good'
    else:
        res = 'bad '
    print res, x, z
```

Output:

```
...
good 254 254
good 255 255
good 256 256
bad  257 257
bad  258 258
bad  259 259
...
```

At this seemingly magic value of `257`, `is` stops working as expected. For some reason, Python makes a new container to hold the calculation result.

However, it only seems to be when a calculation is involved, *and* the value is greater than `256`:

```
>>> 255 is 255
True
>>> 256 is 255 + 1
True
>>> 257 is 257
True
>>> 258 is 257 + 1
False
```

What is so special about `257`? Have I been mislead this entire time and shouldn't be using `is` to compare `int`s?

Comment: I think its related to ascii limit..

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5591958/1222578). Not really to do with ascii, Python *interns* small integers as an optimization.